# Набор разработки для C++ под unix/linux системы

Tags: unix, ide, c++, linux

Нужен совет.

Я программирую на ОС `windows` моя `IDE visual studio`. Хотел, что бы мне посоветовали набор пакетов под `linux` систему с такими требованиями:

- авто завершение кода, с выпадающим списком вариантов
- настройка цветов синтаксиса
- виртуальное пространство для редактирования
- поиск / замена с поддержкой регулярных выражений
- расклад нескольких окон редактирования кода в одном окне
- простой менеджер проекта
- хороший отладчик (который разъясняет суть ошибки + run-time изменение значений переменных + run-time вывод значений переменных) и интегрированный в IDE
- возможность расширить его до возможности разработки с QT.
- быстрый компилятор.

вроде все. хочется чего нить попроще в настройке и эксплуатации и чтоб побыстрей работало.

Comment: «Быстрый компилятор» и «C++» — слабо совместимые понятия.

Comment: все опробовал вроде все норм только вот виртуальное пространство для редактирования нет

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По всем пунктам подходит qtcreator.(ну кроме пункта "который разъясняет суть ошибки", но я и под другие ОС такого не видел).  В большинстве linux дистрибутивов идет в пакетах.

С компилятором тут попроще - под линуксом сейчас два базовых - gcc и clang. Оба достаточно быстры.

Но если хочется хардкора, тогда классика жанра - vim или emacs. С помощью плагинов они хорошо настраиваются под нужные цели (я думаю, за несколько вечеров можно собрать подходящие конфигурации, ну разве что только за исключением qt части).

Comment: @KoVadim по поводу слов   `который разъясняет суть ошибки`   - я подразумевал типо в визуал студио например подсказывает что например ожидается такой то то символ вместо такого то в таком то месте или например не могу преобразовать тип такой то в такой и тп

хардкор не требуется )

Comment: а, с этим у gcc и у clang все более-менее в порядке. Последние версии достаточно хорошо расписывают.  Раньше gcc любил выплевывать большие потоки текста и разобрать, где там ошибка - было сложно. Сейчас достаточно хорошие.

Answer (score 5):

А я бы посоветовал Eclipse поставить в конфигурации для С++. Красиво и удобно.

Comment: спасибо конечно за совет но попробовав eclipse и qtcreator окончательно остановился на qtcreator, прост в настройке и с кучей возможностей. В linux бы еще хороший дебагер вместо GDB для полного счастья.

Comment: @perfect Какой дебагер Вы назвали бы хорошим? GDB  конечно трассировку в обратном направлении не делает, а в остальном вроде лучший.

Comment: мне от microsoft нравился очень удобно с ним работать было. хотя возможно я просто им пользоваться не умею

Comment: почему это gdb не умеет делать трассировку в обратном направлении? все он умеет - [пруф](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ReverseDebug) - уже 4 года как умеет. Более того, QtCreator даже умеет ее пользоваться (но там стоит примечание, что это сильно может тормозить).

Comment: в GDB + qtcreator нет визуализации данных (например realtime просмотр того что хранится в переменной), нельзя в realtime подменить значение переменной и как недавно выяснилось не перехватывает стандартные исключительные ситуации например деление на нуль или утечка памяти. и это только первые впечатления от GDB

Comment: как красиво подмениваются данные:) Вначале говорите о связке gdb+QtCreator, а потом делаете вывод о gdb.

И с каких пор, утечка памяти - это исключительная ситуация?

Comment: утечка не исключительная но все таки msvs ловила ее. а насчет вывода про gdb я писал выше что не умею пользоваться, видимо значит интеграция gdb в qtcreator слабовата. данные не подмениваю просто для меня отладчик не интересен сам по себе потому что работаю только в ide. вот если разработчики qt реализуют полноценную отладку в ide с помощью gdb то я буду рад. ну а поскольку в linux посмотрел разные ide и не увидел реализации отладки ни в одной как у microsoft пришел к выводу что gdb просто не умеет это делать.

Comment: утечки памяти лучше ловить специальным инструментом - valgrind. Либо напишите (поищите?) кастомный менеджер памяти (как собственно майкрософт и сделала) и генерируйте исключение.

И изучайте инструменты. Работать в линуксе и не дружить с консольными приложениями - все равно, что купить купить дорогую машину и держать в гараже в упаковке.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо. Не знал (доки по gdb читал несколько ранее 2009г)